# Components which are not available for changeset

Tags: deployment

Which components are not available in changeset for Migration?

Answer (score 0):

The components available for a change set vary by edition. Click [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_about_components.htm&language=en_US)!

Answer (score 0):

See [Unsupported Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm):

> ## [Unsupported Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm)
>
> Some things you can customize in a Salesforce organization aren’t available in Metadata API.
>
> The following components can’t be retrieved or deployed with Metadata API, and changes to them must be made manually in each of your organizations:
>
> - Account Teams
> - Activity Button Overrides
> - Analytic Settings
> - Automated Case User Settings
> - Auto-number on Customizable Standard Fields
> - Campaign Influences
> - Case Contact Roles
> - Case Feed Layouts
> - Case Team Roles
> - Console Layouts
> - Currency Exchange Rates
> - Data Category Visibility Settings
> - Delegated Administration
> - Divisions
> - Email Services
> - Fiscal Year
> - HTML Document and Attachment Settings
> - Lead Settings
> - Mail Merge Templates
> - Mobile Administration
> - Mobile Users and Devices
> - Multiline layout fields for opportunity teams
> - Offline Briefcase Configurations
> - Opportunity Big Deal Alerts
> - Opportunity Update Reminders
> - Organization Wide Email Addresses
> - Partner Management
> - The following standard picklists: IdeaTheme.Categories, Order.Status,  >-  Question.Origin. (All other standard picklists are supported.)
> - Predefined Case Teams
> - Product Schedule Setup
> - Public and Resource Calendars
> - Quote Templates
> - Salesforce to Salesforce
> - Standard fields that aren’t customizable, such as autonumber fields or system fields
> - Self-Service Portal Font and Colors
> - Self-Service Portal Settings
> - Self-Service Portal Users
> - Self-Service Public Solutions
> - Self-Service Web-to-Case
> - Site.com
> - Social Account/Contact Settings
> - SoftPhone Layout
> - Solution Categories
> - Solution Settings
> - Tag Settings
> - Territory Assignment Rules
> - User Interface Settings (except calendar features, which are supported in ActivitiesSettings)
> - Web Links on Person Account Page Layouts
> - Web-to-Lead

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Can you edit this and add the relevant parts from the link?